# Where do I find the Android SDK Manager settings window on eclipse android bundle?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

This is similar settings I need in the android eclipse bundle running on mac

[image]

Be aware it is not the Android SDK manager which is under the Window - Android SDK manager menu

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's still available, it's just not in the same menu setup as on Win/Linux.  It's in the "Preferences..." menu for the app.  Go to ADT/Eclipse Window->SDK Manager then when the SDK manager is loaded, go to the Android SDK Manager->Preferences...  See screen caps.

[image: ADT Load SDK Manager]
[image: SDK Manager load preferences]
[image: SDK Preferences]